# Calling JavaScript in a WebBrowser control from C#

Tags: c#, javascript

For example:
1) In webBrowser1 page index.html is loaded.
2) This page has the following code:

```
...
<a id="activity_text" href="#" onclick="activity_editor.show();return false;">now status</a>
...
```

3) As I can in the program way to change "now status"?

I tried so:

```
HtmlElement collH1 = document.GetElementById("activity_text");
collH1.InnerText = "new status";
```

But this way works only in the control webBrowser1. 
If then to come to look through IE/Opera/FF that has varied of nothing...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To change value "now status" so that it has varied on a server

Comment: Please clarify the following statement: `If then to come to look through IE/Opera/FF that has varied of nothing...`.  Are you trying to make it so that the text changes at the server and not just in your web browser control?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:

```
HtmlElement collH1 = document.GetElementById("activity_text");
object obj = collH1.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

If you're using mshtml:

```
HtmlElement collH1 = document.GetElementById("activity_text");
mshtml.HTMLAnchorElement el2 = (mshtml. HTMLAnchorElement)collH1.DomElement;
el2.click();
```

This will execute a click similar to a user clicking the link in a browser, which I guess is what you want to accomplish(?).